# JSON nested list to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file which looks like this:

```
    "Aveiro": {
        "Albergaria-a-Velha": {
            "candidates": [
                {
                    "effectiveCandidates": [
                        "JOSÉ OLIVEIRA SANTOS"
                    ],
                    "party": "B.E.",
                    "votes": {
                        "absoluteMajority": 0,
                        "acronym": "B.E.",
                        "constituenctyCounter": 1,
                        "mandates": 0,
                        "percentage": 1.34,
                        "presidents": 0,
                        "validVotesPercentage": 1.4,
                        "votes": 179
                    }
                },
                {
                    "effectiveCandidates": [
                        "ANTÓNIO AUGUSTO AMARAL LOUREIRO E SANTOS"
                    ],
                    "party": "CDS-PP",
                    "votes": {
                        "absoluteMajority": 1,
                        "acronym": "CDS-PP",
                        "constituenctyCounter": 1,
                        "mandates": 5,
                        "percentage": 59.7,
                        "presidents": 1,
                        "validVotesPercentage": 62.5,
                        "votes": 7970
                    }
                },
                {
                    "effectiveCandidates": [
                        "CARLOS MANUEL DA COSTA SERVEIRA VASQUES"
                    ],
                    "party": "CH",
                    "votes": {
                        "absoluteMajority": 0,
                        "acronym": "CH",
                        "constituenctyCounter": 1,
                        "mandates": 0,
                        "percentage": 1.87,
                        "presidents": 0,
                        "validVotesPercentage": 1.95,
                        "votes": 249
                    }
                },
                {
                    "effectiveCandidates": [
                        "RODRIGO MANUEL PEREIRA MARQUES LOURENÇO"
                    ],
                    "party": "PCP-PEV",
                    "votes": {
                        "absoluteMajority": 0,
                        "acronym": "PCP-PEV",
                        "constituenctyCounter": 1,
                        "mandates": 0,
                        "percentage": 1.57,
                        "presidents": 0,
                        "validVotesPercentage": 1.65,
                        "votes": 210
                    }
                },
                {
                    "effectiveCandidates": [
                        "DELFINA LISBOA MARTINS DA CUNHA"
                    ],
                    "party": "PPD/PSD",
                    "votes": {
                        "absoluteMajority": 0,
                        "acronym": "PPD/PSD",
                        "constituenctyCounter": 1,
                        "mandates": 2,
                        "percentage": 24.23,
                        "presidents": 0,
                        "validVotesPercentage": 25.37,
                        "votes": 3235
                    }
                },
                {
                    "effectiveCandidates": [
                        "JESUS MANUEL VIDINHA TOMÁS"
                    ],
                    "party": "PS",
                    "votes": {
                        "absoluteMajority": 0,
                        "acronym": "PS",
                        "constituenctyCounter": 1,
                        "mandates": 0,
                        "percentage": 6.82,
                        "presidents": 0,
                        "validVotesPercentage": 7.14,
                        "votes": 910
                    }
                }
            ],
            "parentTerritoryName": "Aveiro",
            "territoryKey": "LOCAL-010200",
            "territoryName": "Albergaria-a-Velha",
            "total_votes": {
                "availableMandates": 0,
                "blankVotes": 377,
                "blankVotesPercentage": 2.82,
                "displayMessage": null,
                "hasNoVoting": false,
                "nullVotes": 221,
                "nullVotesPercentage": 1.66,
                "numberParishes": 6,
                "numberVoters": 13351,
                "percentageVoters": 59.48
            }
        },
```

The full file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k6lJWyzMzGaYZddtQGc4NARcBs9uE0Pv/view) for reference

I thought that this code would work

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import json_normalize
import json


with open('autarquicas_2021.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

However this is returning the following:

```
df.head()
Aveiro.Albergaria-a-Velha.candidates  ... Évora.Évora.total_votes.percentageVoters
0  [{'effectiveCandidates': ['JOSÉ OLIVEIRA SANTO...  ...                                    49.84

[1 rows x 4312 columns]

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Columns: 4312 entries, Aveiro.Albergaria-a-Velha.candidates to Évora.Évora.total_votes.percentageVoters
dtypes: bool(308), float64(924), int64(1540), object(1540)
memory usage: 31.7+ KB
None
```

For some reason the code is not working, and my research has led me to no solutions, as it seems that every json file has a mind of its own.

**Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!**

Disclaimer: This is for an open source project to bring more transparency into local elections in Portugal. It will not be used for commercial, or for profit projects.

Comment: how do you want the data to look like?

Comment: Does pd.read_json("your_json_file.json") work?

Comment: @HaleemurAli I should've posted that as well. Here you can see an example of that the objective is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSE4IMO4F3Hb8LskV1f1Ct6yN6HM_M0WZoVn6j5gxqAGlniS8ErLjpqO33pdJ06ap7IFwXEY0W8Uw-6/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Comment: @zabop pd.read_json returns ``` Aveiro Açores Beja Braga Bragança  ... Setúbal Viana do Castelo Vila Real Viseu Évora
Albergaria-a-Velha  {'candidates': [{'effectiveCandidates': ['JOSÉ...    NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN  ...     NaN              NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN``` with a df.info() returning ```[2 rows x 20 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 306 entries, Albergaria-a-Velha to Évora
Data columns (total 20 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   Aveiro            19 non-null     object```

Comment: So, I used an online tool and this is the resulting CSV file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSE4IMO4F3Hb8LskV1f1Ct6yN6HM_M0WZoVn6j5gxqAGlniS8ErLjpqO33pdJ06ap7IFwXEY0W8Uw-6/pubhtml?gid=1797460070&single=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_normalize` with a little transformation of original JSON format.

1. Convert JSON into list format.
   I am assuming "Aveiro" as city, and "Albergaria-a-Velha" as district. Apologies of my unfamiliarity of the area, so if it is wrong, please rename the key.

```
res = [{**z, **{'city': x, 'district': y}} for x, y in data.items() for y, z in y.items()]
```

This will transform original JSON of key-values style into list of objects.

```
[{
    "city": "Aveiro",
    "district": "Albergaria-a-Velha",
    "candidates": [{
        ...
}]
```

2. Then use `json_normalize`.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(res, record_path=['candidates'], meta=['total_votes', 'city', 'district'])
```

3. Further expanding the nested object `total_votes`.

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['total_votes'])], axis=1)
```

```
>>> df.iloc[0]
effectiveCandidates                                      [JOSÉ OLIVEIRA SANTOS]
party                                                                      B.E.
votes.absoluteMajority                                                        0
votes.acronym                                                              B.E.
votes.constituenctyCounter                                                    1
votes.mandates                                                                0
votes.percentage                                                           1.34
votes.presidents                                                              0
votes.validVotesPercentage                                                  1.4
votes.votes                                                                 179
total_votes                   {'availableMandates': 0, 'blankVotes': 377, 'b...
city                                                                     Aveiro
district                                                     Albergaria-a-Velha
availableMandates                                                             0
blankVotes                                                                  377
blankVotesPercentage                                                       2.82
displayMessage                                                             None
hasNoVoting                                                               False
nullVotes                                                                   221
nullVotesPercentage                                                        1.66
numberParishes                                                                6
numberVoters                                                              13351
percentageVoters                                                          59.48
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

***Recursive Approach:***

I usually use this function `(a recursive approach)` to do that kind of thing:

```
# Function for flattening 
# json
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
  
    def flatten(x, name =''):
          
        # If the Nested key-value 
        # pair is of dict type
        if type(x) is dict:
              
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
                  
        # If the Nested key-value
        # pair is of list type
        elif type(x) is list:
              
            i = 0
              
            for a in x:                
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
  
    flatten(y)
    return out
```

You can call `flatten_json` for flattening your nested json.

```
# Driver code
print(flatten_json(data))
```

---

***Library-based approach:***

```
from flatten_json import flatten

unflat_json = {'user' :
               {'foo':
                {'UserID':0123456,
                'Email': 'foo@mail.com', 
                'friends': ['Johnny', 'Mark', 'Tom']
                }
               }
              }
  
flat_json = flatten(unflat_json)
  
print(flat_json)
```